# How to find all primary keys which don't have an auto-increment

Tags: mysql

How to find all primary keys in all tables in a database, which don't have an auto-increment identifier to it. We have a large amount of tables and would like to identify all tables which don't have the auto increment identifier on the primary key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extract this information from the `information_schema.columns` table

```
select distinct table_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'DATABASENAME'
      and table_name not in (select table_name
                             from information_schema.columns
                             where table_schema = 'DATABASENAME'
                                   and column_key = 'PRI'
                                   and data_type = 'int'
                                   and extra = 'auto_increment')
```

This looks for all tables in one database having an `auto_increment` column and then returns the remaining tables. This also correctly detects tables with composite keys.

Comment: I would also add `data_type = 'int'` because you don't want to list the PK columns which are character data.

Answer (score 2):

You can find that kind of information in the table `information_schema.columns`. The column `column_key` will be `PRI` and the column `extra` will contain `auto_increment` if it is auto incremented.

```
SELECT
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    column_name
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_key = 'PRI'
    AND extra <> 'auto_increment'
    AND data_type = 'int'
```

In [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32f6d/1/0) you can see that the sample table has "PRI" and "auto_increment" in the respective columns.